# Binding to child item property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have pages with their view models. A `Page` is displaed in a `Frame` using `Frame.NavigationManager.Navigate()`.

In one `Page` I have a `GroupBox` with a child `DataGrid`. I want the `GroupBox` to change it's `Visibility` according to items count in the `DataGrid`.

Here is what I have:

```
<GroupBox ....
          Visibility="{Binding ElementName=SomeDataGrid,
                                   Path=HasItems,
                                   Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
        <DataGrid x:Name="SomeDataGrid"
                  IsReadOnly="True"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
</GroupBox>
```

---

### The Problem

After changing `Page` to another and going back I have the following **binding exception**

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference
>
> 'ElementName=SomeDataGrid'. BindingExpression:Path=HasItems;

I've tried using `x:Reference` but got the same problem.

Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, the `Items` collection is empty at some point and that makes the `GroupBox` become collapsed. When the `GroupBox` gets collapsed, it removes its content (the `DataGrid`) from the view.

With the `DataGrid` removed from the view, the `Binding` can no longer find its reference, so it breaks.

If I were you, I'd bind the `GroupBox` `Visibility` directly to a ViewModel property, instead of binding it to the `DataGrid`.

```
<GroupBox ....
          Visibility="{Binding HasItems,
                               Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
        <DataGrid x:Name="SomeDataGrid"
                  IsReadOnly="True"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
</GroupBox>
```

In the ViewModel:

```
public bool HasItems
{
    get
    {
        return Items != null && Items.Count() > 0;
    }
}

public IEnumerable Items
{
    get
    {
        // ...
    }
    set
    {
        // ...
        RaisePropertyChanged("HasItems");
    }
}
```